# How to bind two Quill Editor instances to different v-models?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, wysiwyg, quill, rich-text-editor

I want to render two `quill editor` elements into one vue component. The editors are supposed to have their own `v-model` attached to them, so they can send data to different databases. I want to differentiate between both editor elements via `description` prop.

**`component.vue`**:

```html
<p>Description:</p>
<text-editor description="true"/>
<p>Content:</p>
<text-editor/>
```

So if `description="true"` a `v-if` directive is triggered and renders the corresponding editor element.

**`text-editor.vue`**:

```html
<template>
  <div id="text-editor" class="text-editor">
    <quill-editor v-if="descr" ref="quillDescr" :modules="modules" :toolbar="toolbar" v-model:content="descr" contentType="html"/>
    <quill-editor v-else ref="quill" :modules="modules" :toolbar="toolbar" v-model:content="content" contentType="html"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter'
import store from "../../../js/store";
import {watch, ref, nextTick, defineProps} from 'vue'
import {Quill} from "@vueup/vue-quill";

const props = defineProps({
    description: false
})

const content = ref('')
const descr = ref('')

const quill = ref(null)
const quillDescr = ref(null)

store.re.body = ''
store.re.descr = ''

let newContent = ''
let newDescr = ''

Quill.debug('error')

watch(content, newValue => {
    newContent = newValue
    store.re.body = newValue
})

watch(descr, newValueDescr => {
    newDescr = newValueDescr
    store.re.descr = newValueDescr
})

watch(
    () => store.re.body,
    newValue => {
        if (newContent === newValue) return
        quill.value.setHTML(newValue)
        // Workaround https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/issues/52
        // move cursor to typing position
        nextTick(() => {
            let q = quill.value.getQuill()
            q.setSelection(newValue.length, 0, 'api')
            q.focus()
        })
    }
)

watch(
    () => store.re.descr,
    newValueDescr => {
        if (newDescr === newValueDescr) return
        quillDescr.value.setHTML(newValueDescr)
        // Workaround https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/issues/52
        // move cursor to typing position
        nextTick(() => {
            let qd = quillDescr.value.getQuill()
            qd.setSelection(newValueDescr.length, 0, 'api')
            qd.focus()
        })
    }
)

const modules = {
    module: BlotFormatter,
}

const toolbar = [
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    [{ size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
    [{ align: [] }],
    [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
    [{ font: [] }],
    ['link', 'image', 'video'],
    ['clean'],
]
</script>
```

Being not very experienced with `watchers`, I've tried duplicating the corresponding `v-model:content`:

```html
<quill-editor v-if="descr" ref="quillDescr" v-model:content="descr"/>
<quill-editor v-else ref="quill" v-model:content="content"/>
```

`ref`:

```js
const quillDescr = ref(null)
store.re.descr = ''
let newDescr = ''
```

as well as watcher parameters:

```js
watch(descr, newValueDescr => {
    newDescr = newValueDescr
    store.re.descr = newValueDescr
})
```

But when I type in one editor field, the other editor field is filled with the letters I'm typing as well:

[image]

How would I configure the watchers so that they only watch the corresponding editor input?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with the DOM manipulation done in `quill.js`, which conflicts with Vue's own management of the virtual DOM.

However, I was able to resolve the issue by implementing the following optimizations.

#### Optimizations

You can significantly reduce the duplication of code and have a single `<quill-editor>` by conditionally setting `store.re.body`/`store.re.descr` based on `props.description`:

```html
<template>
  <div id="text-editor" class="text-editor">
    <quill-editor ref="quill" :modules="modules" :toolbar="toolbar" v-model:content="content" contentType="html" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
⋮
const props = defineProps({
  description: Boolean,
})
      
if (props.description) {
  store.re.descr = ''
} else {
  store.re.body = ''
}

watch(content, newValue => {
  newContent = newValue
        
  if (props.description) {
    store.re.descr = newValue
  } else {
    store.re.body = newValue
  }
})

watch(
  () => props.description ? store.re.descr : store.re.body, 
  newValue => {⋯}
)
⋮
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-quill-update-content-rbzu4k?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyEditor.vue)

But this solution does not scale well if you later need to have the editor update more store properties (e.g., `store.re.title` and `store.re.subtitle`). A better solution would be to make the editor update any given property via a `v-model` implementation:

1. Define a `modelValue` string prop (via `defineProps`).
2. Define an `update:modelValue` emit with a string value (via `defineEmits`).
3. In the watch that sets `store.re.body`/`store.re.descr`, emit the `update:modelValue` event with new value.
4. In the watch for `store.re.body`/`store.re.descr`, change the watch's source to be `props.modelValue`.

```html
<script setup>
⋮
1️⃣
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: String,
})
2️⃣
const emit = defineEmits({
  'update:modelValue': value => true,
})

watch(content, newValue => {
  newContent = newValue
              3️⃣
  emit('update:modelValue', newValue)
})

watch(
  () => props.modelValue, 4️⃣
  newValue => {⋯}
)
⋮
</script>
```

Then in the parent component, use `v-model` to bind `store.re.body`/`store.re.descr`:

```html
<text-editor v-model="store.re.descr" />
<text-editor v-model="store.re.body" />
```

For some reason, setting `store.re.body` and `store.re.descr` in the parent component does not update the `v-model` in this case, but you can workaround that by using a computed prop. To make the changes to `store.re.body` reactive in this example:

```html
<template>
  <text-editor v-model="body" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'

const body = computed({
  get: () => store.re.body,
  set: v => store.re.body = v,
})
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-quill-update-content-hyztcj?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyEditor.vue)